# Python: Cerberus Value Coercion if len(value) == 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, cerberus

Using the `cerberus` library for validation, I am wondering how a custom rule might look like that checks if the input is a list with only ONE element. If this is the case, the value should be changed to a single value (Value Coercion).

Here's my try, which is not working.

```
from cerberus import Validator


class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_is_one_elem_list(self, is_one_elem_list, field, value):
        """{'type': 'boolean'}"""

        if is_one_elem_list and isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:
            self.value = value[0]  # self.value doesn't exist, so that's wrong. How to do better?


v = MyValidator()

schema = {"amount": {"is_one_elem_list": True, "type": "list"}}
print(v.validated({"amount": [10]}, schema))
```

Output is `{'amount': [10]}`.
However, it should read `{'amount': 10}`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `self.value = value[0]` with `self.document[field] = value[0]`.

Adjusting the method using the `check_with` functionality (https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#check-with) further simplifies the whole thing.

```
from cerberus import Validator


class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _check_with_is_one_elem_list(self, field, value):

        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:
            self.document[field] = value[0]


v = MyValidator()

schema = {"amount": {"check_with": "is_one_elem_list", "type": "list"}}
assert v.validated({"amount": [10]}, schema) == {"amount": 10}
```